# Adding ng-init code from json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind value of ng-init to a input from an json object.

However I get "Syntax Error: Token" where am I going wrong ?

```
$scope.obj = { init: 'obj.value = obj.value || 20' };
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/nmaxLvbqijXPBKoaQTUQ?p=preview

Comment: Just remove curly brackets. it should work

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-required` instead of `ng-init`

```
<form name="someformname">
  <input type="text" name="someinputname" ng-model="obj.value" ng-required="{{obj.init}}" /> 
</form>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: why cant u use this ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider init as a function which changes the value of the obj.

```
$scope.obj = { 
    init: function(){
          $scope.obj.value = $scope.obj.value || 20;
         } 
};

<input type="text" name="someinputname" ng-model="obj.value" ng-init="obj.init()" />
```

See the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0D397Q3vKejFKSGqaNCN?p=preview)

Comment: But the value of the input field is not set to 20 by default.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the following code:

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="someinputname" ng-model="obj.value" ng-init="loadObj()" />
```

**js**

```
 $scope.obj = {
    value: null
 };

 $scope.loadObj = function() {
     $scope.obj = { 
        init:  {
          value:  $scope.obj.value | 20
        }
     };

   $scope.obj = $scope.obj.init;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```
ng-init="$eval(obj.init)"
```

[PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/TV44HhEgB64CUrQU0uE3?p=preview)

`ng-init` internally does this: `scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit)`, so the expression above will be executed this way:

```
scope.$eval('$eval(obj.init)')
```

which executes the expression stored in `obj.init`.

Simply removing the curly brackets, as suggested in comments, will not work because it would result into the following call:

```
scope.$eval('obj.init')
```

which simply returns the value of `obj.init` but does **NOT** execute it!